# Public key validation using jsch library or java

Tags: java, validation, key, public, jsch

When I generate a public key using java library means, it shows like

```
Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 90455558766847231187855444386104902055754158435274375899360135171624950510999..
  public exponent: 65537
```

When I generate using any online portals such as http://travistidwell.com/blog/2013/09/06/an-online-rsa-public-and-private-key-generator/
    it shows like

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgE3xIde7MizPdmyJ3GgDmPcLsfAY
.............
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Actually the problem is:
If i am validating public key using default java library

```
PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
                    .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(pub));
```

I am getting invalid key error.

If anyone knows, how to validate these keys with JSCH library or validate portal generated public key using java default library.

Comment: What do you mean by *"validate these keys"*? What's your use case? - What does it mean *"it shows like"* - What do you do to *"show"* it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

But maybe, you are looking for [`KeyPair.writeSECSHPublicKey`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPair.html#writeSECSHPublicKey-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-):

```
/**
 * Writes the public key with the specified comment to the output stream in
 * the format defined in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt
 * @param out output stream 
 * @param comment comment
 */
public void writeSECSHPublicKey(java.io.OutputStream out, String comment)

/**
 * Writes the public key with the specified comment to the output stream in
 * the format defined in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt
 * @param name file name
 * @param comment comment
 * @see #writeSECSHPublicKey(java.io.OutputStream out, String comment)
 */
public void writeSECSHPublicKey(String name, String comment)
```